# Getting error 'no such file or directory' when reading file in samba folder

Tags: go

I want to read the following **test.html** file. I have mounted it in my **ubuntu 16.04** machine and I can access it.
But how can I read the file in go?
I get the error `no such file or directory`

```
url := `smb://192.168.32.114/test/test.html`
dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile(url)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

Comment: Two things check if you are using the shared folder also check for permissions provided to access from outside.

Comment: Himanshu, any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Check using `smbclient -L SERVERNAME | grep -i "YOURSHARENAME"` in terminal for shared files.

Comment: That's not a filename, that's a URL. Access the file via the mount point instead.